# SE Android app's feed changing once a quarter

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

I searched for a question like this but I didn't see anything, suggesting this perhaps is not a bug but maybe user-side error. I'm tagging it as bug anyway because I'm pretty good with software and feel I should be able to figure out how to fix it if it's possible.

It seems for me that the feed on the Android app changes every quarter. It changed for the first time in months in the beginning of July; before that it had gotten all the way up to "*Earlier this quarter*". Now it says "*Earlier this month*".

If this is not a bug, how do I change this strange feature so it's up to date? (Note: I've tried pull down refresh.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's per quarter, but I noticed that the feed doesn't refresh daily/every time the app is opened since the addition of hot network questions on feed. Probably same issue or not, I'm not sure.

Comment: I kind of believe that the feed (on v1.0.84 beta, but observed since quite long time) won't automatically refresh anymore until you manually pull-to-refresh. However, this needs confirmation from SE devs.